# Generate strong pseudo random digit to be used as voucher code

Tags: python, random, cryptography, payment

I need to generate a strong pseudo random digit (string consisting of only characters 0-9) with length of N.

The generated string needs to be hard to predict in order to be used as a voucher code in a payment system.

Please review my code. This is what I have come up with:

```
import os
import binascii.hexlify
import random

def get_string_random_digit(n):
    r = os.urandom(n*2)
    ri = int(binascii.hexlify(r), 16)
    arr = list(str(ri))
    while len(arr) > n:
        random.shuffle(arr)
        arr.pop()
    return str(''.join(arr))
```

os.urandom is supposed to be safe to be used in cryptography so I assumed it would be safe enough to use in a payment system for vouchers.

The system will run on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if it's relevant (urandom is dependent on OS implementation apparently).

I first generate a string of length N*2 with os.urandom. Then I us built in Python random module to reduce the string to half of its length.

Any suggestions?

Is this safe enough?

Comment: You should use `SystemRandom`, not `Random` for anything security related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.urandom()` returns *bytes*, so you should just reinterpret them as a `long` or `int`; you chose to convert it first to hexadecimal and then further convert it to `int`; this works fine and will work for arbitrary long numbers.  You could have used `struct` to achieve this in one step, but this will not work for very large numbers, so I think that step is just fine (unless you want to do this millions of times each second).

You should strip that `random.shuffle` part, though.  It does not add any "randomness" to your values.  Just use `str(ri)[-n:]` if you need a string of length `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
from random import SystemRandom
def get_random_string(n):
    return int(SystemRandom().random()*10**n)
```